# sql select 5 higest values

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, select-query

I'm trying to select the 5 rows with the highest `count` value

This is my query:

```
string sql = "SELECT   top 5  count FROM  Likes  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC";
```

It's just throwing an error code that

> Column 'Likes.count' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

It's for a project I've got to present tomorrow...  [image]

Comment: what you means highest count? provide example data, and data structure if possible

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL?

Comment: Transact-SQL, because he used TOP :)

Comment: @DikaArtaKarunia i'll hadd more coloumns to that table, and i would like to get the 5 columns with the highest value of count(it's not count-that's only the name.threat it as 'price')

Comment: use sub query to populate 5 highest price first select the id for example and then select main table with filter the id, example `select * from table where id in(select top 5 id from table order by price asc)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On SQL Server, simply do this:

```
 SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Likes ORDER BY [Count] DESC
```

This assumes that your `Likes`-table already contains a column named `[Count]` meaning that you don't need to count the records yourself (which is what `COUNT(*)` does).

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `COUNT(*)` here for `order by`.

```
SELECT   top 5  [count] FROM  Likes  ORDER BY [Count] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

`count` is a reserved word which is why you should stay clear of using them for column names. If you don't want to rename the column you can escape it, different dbms may effect who you do this. In ssms you would use square brackets.

```
string sql = "SELECT   top 5  [count] FROM  Likes  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC";
```